# Стилистика русского языка

Tags: стилистика, причастия, местоимения

Добрый день! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, будет ли стилистически обосновано использовать в сложноподчиненном предложение причастие. Пример:

***В голове начало проясняться и появилась граничащая с помешательством и ломающие все внутренние преграды мысль , что его просто напугали и бросили.***

И обязательно ли местоимения ( который, которая и др.) должны стоять сразу после определяемого слова? 
пример:

***В голове начало проясняться и забрезжила мысль , что его просто напугали и бросили, которая сразу сбрасывала животный инстинкт, граничащий с помешательством.***

Заранее спасибо! С большим уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Антон, лучше написать "использовать в предложенИИ (П.п., на -ИЕ); существительные, оканчивающиеся на -ИЙ, -ИЕ,-ИЯ в р.д.п. падежах оканчиваются на -И.
Крооме того, мысль какАЯ? граничащАЯ, ломающАЯ (во втором причастии тоже должно быть окончание -АЯ). Использование в предложении причастия может быть связано со стилем, а не с видом сложного предложения. Поэтому используйте на здоровье.  Предложение должно выглядеть так.
  В голове начало проясняться и появилась граничащая с помешательством и ломающая все внутренние преграды мысль , что его просто напугали и бросили.(запятая перед И не нужна, так как есть общий второстепенный член - "в голове")

Во втором  Вашем предложении местоимение "который"  обязательно должно стоять ПОСЛЕ определяемого слова. Кроме того, слово сбрасывало хорошо бы заменить или взять в кавычки, чтобы не было речевой ошибки. Тогда правильный вариант будет выглядеть так.
В голове начало проясняться и забрезжила мысль , что его просто напугали и бросили. Она сразу "отключала" животный инстинкт, граничащий с помешательством.
Антон, "отключала" - один из вариантов, возможно, не самый удачный.